# Closing container with class (not id) on mouse out or click out

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML

```
<ul class="actions">
    <li><span class="toggle"></span>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="entypo-eye">View File</span></li>
            <li><span class="entypo-download">Download File</span></li>
            <li><span class="entypo-export">Send File</span></li>
            <li><span class="entypo-circled-info">File Properties</span></li>
            <li><span class="entypo-login">Copy To...</span></li>
            <li><span class="entypo-trash">Delete File</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my JS

```
$('.actions .toggle').click(function(){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
});
```

So what I am trying to do now is making the container close on mouseout and/or when someone clicks on another part of the page (any part) --- I need to show an example of each of these (mouseout/click out). So it would be a lot easier to do this when the container in question has an ID, not a class.

But in this case, it can't have an ID because there are going to be several of these kinds of containers on the page. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: on mouseout of which element

Comment: Do what you want, but I don't think `mouseover` or `mouseout` are actual _actions_; at least not in the way you're intending to use them. I drag my cursor across tons of things that I don't intend to _act_ upon. Sure, a mouseover effect such as a highlight is okay, but expanding a menu under my cursor, or hiding one when it leaves (ffs), is super annoying. Just my opinion; take it or leave it.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kzFQ3/3/ - the mouseout is not implemented as the requirement is not clear

Comment: @naomik I agree with you, `mouseover` etc is not really an action. I hate that junk too. I'm pushing for a click event on my project. Thanks everyone for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use `find()` instead of `next()` first you need to go to parent `li` using `parent()` as find will search in descendant elements. You can learn more about jQuery api [here](http://api.jquery.com/).

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5mz3B/)**

```
$('.actions .toggle').click(function(){  
    $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
});
```

To hide the ul when clicked out side you can try something like

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5mz3B/1/)**

```
$('.actions .toggle').click(function(event){  
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();

});

$('body').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('toggle'))
       $('.toggle').parent().find('ul').hide();
});
```

Comment: Oh, one thing this allows though is opening more than one of these containers. Ideally, you could only open one at a time. Hmm.. I have to look at this closer.

Answer (score 0):

try this to toggel parent ul using [jquery closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$('.actions .toggle').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('ul').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

and mouseout..

you should use .mouseout() .

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Whoami/LJ85t/)

```
$('.actions .toggle').mouseover(function(){  
    $(this).parent().find('ul').show();
});

$('.actions .toggle').mouseout(function(){  
    $(this).parent().find('ul').hide();
});
```

and

[other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007550/hide-div-when-mouseout)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="show_div"> Sort summary <br /> Second Row</div>
<div class="hide_div" style="display:none"> Long Summary <br /> Second Row<br /> Third Row <br /> Fourth Row</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $(".show_div").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).next().show();
        $(this).hide("slow");
    });

    $(".hide_div").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).prev().show();
        $(this).hide("slow");

    });
});


    http://jsfiddle.net/UG3FZ/
```